# Facebook app stopped posting updates to the wall

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-wall

Since Thursday our Facebook App has stopped posting updates to our page without any changes from our side.The error we got is

> "OAuthException: (#200) User does not have sufficient administrative
>   permission for this action on this page"

but the permissions are all set properly (user = manager, app has access to wall etc) and our server gets the token back with the permission to post.

Has anyone experienced this issue lately and are there any solutions or suggestions to fix this?

Comment: Seems to happen to me every once in a while, too.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will help you, but solved it for me. Using the graph explorer I found with the APP_TOKEN it would not work, however changing this to the USER_TOKEN worked perfectly.